# taking data from multiple tables in single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oledb

I have following table as LocalBarcode:

[image]

and following as Barcodecancel [image]cancel :

I want to take:

1. count of total barcodes
2. count of barcodes whose IsUpload is true

from LocalBarcode and

1. count of Barcode whose isUpload is true

from BarcodeCancel.

I designed following query:

```
select  localbarcode.(select count(barcode)  
                        from localbarcode 
                       where Int([TimeStamp])= Format(CDate('10/18/2013'))), 
        localbarcode.(select count(isupload)  
                        from localbarcode 
                       where isupload=0), 
        BarcodeCancel.(select count(barcode)  
                        from BarcodeCancel 
                       where Int([TimeStamp])= Format(CDate('10/18/2013'))) 
      from localbarcode,BarcodeCancel
```

But this query is giving me error on first line.

Please help me.

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: You lack a basic understanding of SQL joins. I suggest you read up before going any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select  (select count(barcode)  
                    from localbarcode 
                   where Int([TimeStamp])= Format(CDate('10/18/2013'))), 
            (select count(isupload)  
                    from localbarcode 
                   where isupload=0), 
            (select count(barcode)  
                    from BarcodeCancel 
                   where Int([TimeStamp])= Format(CDate('10/18/2013'))) 
     from dual
```

You need to use the dummy table "dual". I made a simplified try out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15291/3

Comment: I attached from "localbarcode,BarcodeCancel" to your query and query run, but its returning me multiple rows, i just wanted it in single row

Comment: mysql allows to use a dummy table called `dual`

Comment: sir, i am getting correct result, but with multiple rows, look at my edit, (last image) ,can it be in single row?

Comment: The multiple rows come from the tables. Use `from dual`. This tables has no content, because it is dummy. Your `localbarcode,BarcodeCancel` does effectively give you the result for as many times as there are rows in `localbarcode` multiplied by the number of rows in `BarcodeCancel`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get required output using following query:

select count(LocalBarcode.Barcode), count(lb.Barcode), count(lb1.Barcode) from LocalBarcode left join LocalBarcode lb on LocalBarcode.Barcode = lb.Barcode and LocalBarcode.IsUpload = 1 left join Barcodecancel lb1 on LocalBarcode.Barcode = lb1.Barcode and LocalBarcode.roleIsUpload = 1

Comment: error on this line:LocalBarcode.Barcode = LocalBarcode.Barcode as : join expression not supported

Answer (score 1):

You can also get result using following query:

select count(*) barcodes_total, (select count(*) from LocalBarcode where IsUpload =1) barcodes_upload_total, (select count(*) from Barcodecancel where IsUpload =1) Barcodecancel_upload_total from LocalBarcode